# How to draw a View on a canvas by giving the x , y postion?

Tags: android

How can i draw a view on a canvas by giving the x,y position in the canvas.

For example,
I have custom view myView, which was created by inflating one of my layout.xml file.
Now i want to draw this myView on the canvas at position (x, y).

How can i do that?

Please help with your ideas.

Thanks,
Sen

**Updated:**

To be more specific,
I have

```
myView extend view { 
... 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
super.onDraw(canvas);  
    { Inside which i will draw a curve }
```

Then I will obtain 8 set of co-ordinates along the path and will store it in a list.

Then i have created a new view by using Absolute layout and its name is myinfo.xml(which contains two text views) present inside the res/layouts folder.

Now i want to inflate this view inside the onDraw method and want to place them in the above collected co-ordinates.

But i tried to inflate the view in this class(myView) but it is not working.

Please tell where am i wrong??

If you have some other suggestion, do update me.

Thanks & Regards,
Sen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`save()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save%28%29) on your Canvas to save the properties. Then you can do any operations you like, e.g. call [clipRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) to clip the region of your view and then draw it on the canvas.

After you are done, call [`restoreToCount(int saveCount)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restoreToCount%28int%29) using the integer returned by the save() command before to restore the Canvas' properties. :-)